# Office.js API - Add nested content control in word file

Tags: angular, office365, office-js

I am developing an plugin for Office Word, I want to add feature that allows user to add content in hierarchical order in form of nested content control.

```
        let wordContentControl:any;
        Word.run(async context => {
           
            const range = context.document.getSelection();
            range.clear();
            wordContentControl = range.insertContentControl();
            wordContentControl.tag = "NameTest";
            wordContentControl.insertText("Sample", 'End');
            wordContentControl.cannotEdit = false;
            wordContentControl.appearance = 'BoundingBox';

            wordContentControl.font.color = 'red';
            await context.sync()


        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
        Word.run(async context => {
            var contentControlsWithTag = context.document.contentControls.getByTag('NameTest');
            // Queue a command to load the tag property for all of content controls.
            context.load(contentControlsWithTag, 'tag');

            // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands,
            // and return a promise to indicate task completion.
            return context.sync().then(function () {
                if (contentControlsWithTag.items.length === 0) {
                    console.log('No content control found.');
                }
                else {
                    return context.sync()
                        .then(function () {
                           
                            context.sync();
                            var ccs = context.document.contentControls;
                            
                            ccs.load("NameTest");
                            
                            console.log("Nr cc: " + ccs.items.length);
                            let cc = ccs.items[0];

                        });
                }
            });
        });
```

This is what I have done so far. but I am unable to find a way to add content control within/nested content control.
Your help would be much helpfull for me.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested and calling `insertContentControl` inside a content control should work:

```
var contentControl = context.document.getSelection().insertText('outer\n', Word.InsertLocation.start).insertContentControl();
contentControl.insertText('inner', Word.InsertLocation.end).insertContentControl();
```

[image: Result screenshot]

Please see if this works for you.

Comment: Here I am developing further and trying to add styles to content control, its working fine with Word Online, but its not working with Word Desktop. Getting error : 
`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): InvalidArgument: InvalidArgument
RichApi.Error: InvalidArgument
    at new n (word-win32-16.01.js:26)
    at n.o.processRequestExecutorResponseMessage (word-win32-16.01.js:26)
    at word-win32-16.01.js:26
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:232)
    at Object.onInvoke (ng_zone.js:594)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:231)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:114)
    at zone.js:502...`

Comment: That would be a different issue. I saw you posted the new question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70164988/office-js-angular-word-content-control-style-not-working-with-word-in-desktop; let's see if someone could help there.

Comment: That's strange, its behaviour is totally different in the web browser (online) and desktop (windows).